# ¿Delinear una caja de texto verde cuando está bien digitada la información y cuando no esté bien digitada delinearla de rojo?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Estoy validando que al momento que un usuario ingrese un correo no válido los bordes del input text se pongan rojos y cuando es válido en verde. ¿Me podrían colaborar con eso? Este es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <form>
    <p>
   
   <label>Correo</label><input name='EMAILPERSONIGRAMA' id='PERSONIGRAMAEMAIL' autocomplete='off' required >
    <span id="emailOK"></span>
</p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('PERSONIGRAMAEMAIL').addEventListener('input', function() {
    campo = event.target;
    valido = document.getElementById('emailOK');
        
    emailRegex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
  
    if (emailRegex.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido";
    } else {
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto";
    }
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Santiago, podrías por favor copiar y pegar el código en la pregunta. Ya que por imagen es muy difícil poder realizar pruebas del programa.

Comment: Vale, ya te edito.

Comment: Podrias usar la etiqueta <input type="email" /> de html5.
Te pone en rojo cuando está mal y te sale un bocadillo con un mensaje editable.
http://www.anerbarrena.com/html5-email-input-1837/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo usando:

- `CSS`: con una clase para el exito (`valid`) y otra para el error (`invalid`).
- [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/className): Dependiendo de si es correcto o incorrecto el valor asignar la clase correspondiente.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('PERSONIGRAMAEMAIL').addEventListener('input', function() {
    campo = event.target;
    valido = document.getElementById('emailOK');
        
    emailRegex = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;
  
    if (emailRegex.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido";
      campo.className = 'valid';
    } else {
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto";
      campo.className = 'invalid';
    }
});
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
input.valid {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label>Correo</label><input name='EMAILPERSONIGRAMA' id='PERSONIGRAMAEMAIL' autocomplete='off' required />
    <span id="emailOK"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: De verdad ha sido de gran ayuda! Muchas gracias :)